# Image loaded using tf.keras.utils.load_img() is not displaying correctly

Tags: image, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have an image of a face that is rotated 90 degrees:

[image: rotated face]

I now load the image twice (once using IPython and once using `tf.keras.utils.load_img()`:

[image]

As you can see, the image loaded using IPython is displayed correctly. The image loaded using `tf.keras.utils.load_img()` is displayed **without** the rotation.

Is this expected behavior? If not, am I doing something wrong?

Links to the code and image can be found [here](https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#maxt5za30y3ykxdnh4fwn).

Comment: You are not using PIL to load the first image. See this: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4703#issuecomment-645219973

Comment: @AloneTogether Thank you so much! Knowing that keras doesn't do anything with the exif rotation tag is super helpful.